# Keep the same auto increment id for multiple values

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table in my database called university with 3 columns: 'uni id', 'uni name' and 'student id'. I've added an auto increment value, the 'uni id'. When a student select the university name (let's say 'University A'), the ID should be 1 and the 'student id' will be updated with the id of the student. That's fine. But if another user selects the same university ('University A'), the 'uni id' will automatically change to 2 (obviously, it's an auto increment value yep). The 'uni name' will stay the same 'University A' and a new student id will be inserted in the table.

Is there any way I can keep the same uni id for specific uni names? 
For example:

- uni id | uni name | student id
- ---1---|---Uni A---|-----S10----
- ---1---|---Uni A---|-----S37----

Also, I have a second table, can I pass the uni id in that table? For example:

- uni id | course id
- ---1---| --CS90---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The MyISAM engine allows you to use auto_increment as a component of a compound PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: This would work, but is a poor solution, imo. Normalizing your database will save you a lot of potential headaches

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create an additional table. You want one table that stores the universities and another table with students

Universities table

```
uni_id uni_name
1      uni A
```

Students table

```
uni_id student_id ID (Primary key)
1      S10        1
1      S37        2
```

Comment: thanks. uni_id is an auto increment value right? How can we pass it to students table?

Comment: it would stay an auto-increment in the Universities table, but would be a `foreign key` in the students table. You would want a primary key on the students table as well.

Comment: I see, I'll change the tables now. But still the uni id will keep changing. I have a form where students add their uni details, so when a student fill the form and choose a uni, the uni_id (auto-increment value) will always change. If students select the same uni (i.e. uni A), then uni A will have multiple uni_id. Hope u get what I mean and thank you for your help